# ColumnCount on frontpage doesn't work

Tags: category, magento-1.8, frontend, css, class

I'm trying to add the class "first" and "last" to my categories on the frontpage, but it only adds the "first" class - AND to all of the list items. Can someone please help me with this?

My .phtml looks like this:

```
<?php $_categories=$this->getStoreCategories();?>
<div class="category-grid">
    <h3><span class="leftline"></span><span class="middle">Her kan du købe</span><span class="rightline"></span></h3>
    <ul>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
        <?php $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()); ?>
        <?php $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer'); ?>
        <?php $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category); ?>
        <?php if($_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <li class="list-item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?>">
                <span class="linkimage"><img src="<?php echo $_imageUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $_category->getName()?>" /></span>
                <span class="linktitle"><?php echo $_category->getName()?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>`
Doesn't this mean that the `<li>` element will be added only if `$i%_columnCount` is 0. Then it will look through the categories and print the next one that matches this condition? In this case you will never have the 'last' column.
Try this:

```
<?php $_categories=$this->getStoreCategories();?>
<div class="category-grid">
    <h3><span class="leftline"></span><span class="middle">Her kan du købe</span><span class="rightline"></span></h3>
    <ul>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
        <?php $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()); ?>
        <?php $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer'); ?>
        <?php $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category); ?>
        <?php if($_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):?>
        <li class="list-item<?php if($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif(($i+1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?>">
                <span class="linkimage"><img src="<?php echo $_imageUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $_category->getName()?>" /></span>
                <span class="linktitle"><?php echo $_category->getName()?></span>
            </a>
            <?php $i++;?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be on to something, but this wasn't the solution. The "first" class is still the only class being added, and still to all list items.

Comment: @ThomasUrupMichaelsen. probably. I didn't test the code, but I think the idea is good. I will investigate. Just to get it. You are listing only categories with images?

Comment: I'm only listing categories with images and title, yes.
Thanks mate

Comment: @ThomasUrupMichaelsen. Make sure that column count is not 1. If it is it won't work because you will always get `$i%$_columnCount==0` and you will never reach the `elseif` statement

Comment: Thanks mate, I figured out, that I need to add the columncount to the CMS block, I've added! Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.